# Facebook SDK for android always return session status Created

Tags: android, facebook, session

In my app i have facebook login,it was working perfectly till yesterday but today when i was testing it returns session status Created.i have tried many times on different device but same response.my onCreate Code is -

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and code of onCreateView of my fragment is -

```
authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
if (state.isOpened()) {
            accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
            accessExpir = session.getExpirationDate();

            if (state.isOpened()) {
                if(mDialog==null){
                    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                }
                if(!mDialog.isShowing()){
                    mDialog.setMessage("please wait...");
                    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    mDialog.show();
                }
                 Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                     public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                          session.close();
                          getUserFacebookData(user);
                     }
                 });
             }
    }else if(state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED)){
    }
    else if (state.isClosed()) {
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

onResume()  method is called and then it shows session status -

```
{Session state:CREATED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:**************}
```

any one can please help me,i have already spend my whole day on it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After spend a lot of of time found solution to my own problem and sharing it-

added few more lines of code in onResume() workes for me -

```
Session s = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(s);
        s.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email")));
```